# Angular - ngModel is not updating the value to the component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-ngmodel

The ngModel is not working. I'm using it with textbox.

app.component.html

```
<input type="text" [value]="name" [ngModel]="name">
Name is: {{name}}
```

app.component.ts

```js
name = '';
constructor() { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.name = "Hello";
}
```

When I change the textbox value, the value is not changing in the component. But the two-way data binding is working with `[(ngModel)]="name"`. Please help.

Comment: The syntax you are using `[ngModel]` is one-way binding you have to use two-way binding syntax `[(ngModel)]="value"`. To remember it easily I call it `banana in a box`,


One way binding: If you change the value the change will reflect in the control

Two way binding: If values or input changes, changes will reflect both ways

Comment: Yes, but I want one way data binding using [ngModel]. My issue is one way data binding is not working, when I keep console log in save button.

Comment: Well if you want the changes to refect in variable if you change value in text box, you will either have to use two way binding on use `ngModelChange ` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`ngModel` description](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#description),

> If you have a one-way binding to ngModel with [] syntax, changing the domain model's value in the component class sets the value in the view. If you have a two-way binding with [()] syntax (also known as 'banana-in-a-box syntax'), the value in the UI always syncs back to the domain model in your class.

Either you can work with `[(ngModel)]`, the two-way binding as you mentioned,

or you need to have the [`(ngModelChange)`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#properties) event binding to update the variable with the input's value.

```
<input
  type="text"
  [ngModel]="name"
  (ngModelChange)="name = $event"
/>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-338slc?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thanks, Yong. So, is ngModelChange is mandatory to update the value in component when we are using [ngModel]?

Comment: Yes, `(ngModelChange)` is an event emitter that will be triggered when there is a change for `ngModel` value. Hence you use the trigger to update the variable in the component.

Comment: Okay, so without ngModelChange, it wont update the model, is that correct?